# Textarea with javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex

How can I validate the following textarea using a pure Javascript not Jquery? Can anyone help me please.

```
<script>
function val()
{
    // 1. only allowed alphanumeric characters, dash(-), comma(,) and no space
    // 2. alert if person is trying to input not allowed chars as in 1.
} 
</script>

<form>  
    <textarea name="pt_text" rows="8" cols="8" class="input" onkeydown="return val();"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you google the regular expression for your need?

Comment: Just a suggestion for point 2.  When you say alert, please don't use an actual alert box.

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery?

Comment: onkeydown isnt really a good for validating stuffs.. what if someone copy pastes with mouse o_O

Comment: @Deja Vu, because it's clearly a homework/test question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
document.querySelector('.input').onkeypress = function validate(e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[\w,-]/) == null) {
        alert('not allowed');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vm5b/1/)

Edit: As pointed out by tenub, `\w` also allows `_`, so modify the regex to: `/[A-Za-z0-9,-]/`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vm5b/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match only valid strings:

```
/^[\w,-]*$/
```

Use + instead of * if you don't allow empty strings.

Comment: Ah, right. `/^[-\w,-[_]]*$/` if character class subtraction is supported, otherwise `/^[a-zA-Z0-9,-]*$/`. (Probably use the last one anyway for readability.)